# Strict convexity of a function in a given domain

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, maxima-minima

If function $f(\mathbf x)$ is strictly convex at all stationary points in a given domain, $\mathbf x\in[\underline{\mathbf x},\overline{\mathbf x}]$, does it mean that the function may only have local minima in the range and this local minimum is unique in the range i.e., there is only one local minimum in the domain ?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. However, it seems related to this: if a differentiable function is strictly convex and $x$ is a critical point in the interior of its domain, then $x$ is a global strict minimiser for the function.

Comment: What does it mean to be strictly convex at a point ? That we can find a neighbourhood of the point such that etc... ? If so, then we cannot deduce anything about the number of local minimas ...

Comment: I have a differentiable function in which the Hessian is strictly positive definite at all critical points of the interior of the set $[\underline{\mathbf x},\overline{\mathbf x}]$. I was wondering this implicates that there can only be at most one local minima in the set.

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$$ f(x,y)=(x^2-1)(x^2+1)+(y-x^2+1)^2$$
on $[-2,2]\times[-\frac12,\frac12]$.